# Corrupted .viminfo file

Tags: linux, vim, filesystems

Somehow my .viminfo file inside /home/username is corrupted. So, ls -al command gives this output for .viminfo file only

```
-??????????  ? ?       ?           ?            ? .viminfo
```

Therefore, the vim editor cannot write into this file when opened as "username" user. I have tried a lot to fix it, but failed. Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. Since it is corrupted, I cannot remove it. I get this error "rm: cannot remove â.viminfoâ: Input/output error".

Comment: Try as root (`sudo rm`); if that still fails, I'd recommend a file system check (`fsck`).

Answer (score 5):

Do this:

```
rm -f ~/.viminfo
```

or

```
sudo rm -f ~/.viminfo
```

If the first one fails.

The `.viminfo` file contains useful but non-critical data about your vim. However, yours is corrupt so you should remove it.

You can also move it to a different place if you think it may contain some important things that you don't want to lose.

Comment: That's the problem. I cannot delete it since it is completely corrupted. The above command gives this output: "rm: cannot remove â/home/username/.viminfoâ: Input/output error".

Comment: Could you use a finder gui application to send it to trash? Does that give an error? Make sure you have show hidden files enabled.

Comment: The file is not shown in the filesystem in the GUI (probably, since it is corrupted) even if I enabled to show hidden files. I can see other hidden files.

Comment: Try running `fsck` (file system check) and see if that works. Make sure that you unmount anything your in filesystem if it is mounted.